# Does an h2 (heading) contained in a child <div> weight less than an h1 contained in the parent to the search engine?

Tags: html, search-engine

I have been told that metadata does not mean as much to the search engines as it did in the past.

The site I am creating does not contain headings because it's mostly illustrations with links so I decided to have a heading in the same color as the background in order to give accessibility to the page.

I wonder if I can do it loosely in a child div or if I should indent the heading -9999px in the parent. And also if font size would count as a criteria for the SE.

Comment: a h2 will always weight less then a h1. And in a child div it will have a lesser meaning for the page, but more meaning for that particular div. As far as I know font size doe not matter.

Comment: Check out [this tutorial](http://www.hobo-web.co.uk/seo-tutorial/) which is fairly recent (April 2013). It is long, but contains LOTS of great info.

Comment: @Neograph734 how about indentation?

Comment: @Neograph734 Will do. Thanks. I'd vote your comments up if I could.

Comment: @csmckelvey Will do. Thanks. I'd vote your comments up if I could.

Comment: The title and the body of your question contain *different* questions. What is it exactly that you want to know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this tutorial](http://www.hobo-web.co.uk/seo-tutorial/) which is fairly recent (April 2013). It is long, but contains LOTS of great info.

Comment: You [should](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/193139) include the relevant information of the linked page in your answer. Think what happens when this page goes 404 (as it is currently the case for me): this answer would be of no use to anyone anymore.